# Theoretical Computer Science - context-sensitive grammar?

Tags: grammar

how can it be that the rule "Aa -> aA" is context-sensitive? According to the definition, context-sensitive rules have to be like this form:

```
αAβ → αγβ
```

where

```
A ∈ N,  α,β ∈ (N∪Σ)*   and γ ∈ (N∪Σ)+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. If you scroll down the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition), you can [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) that, formally,

*cB → Bc*

does *not* fit the scheme, but it can be simulated by 4 rules that *do* fit it:

3. *c  B   →   W   B*
4. *W  B   →   W   X*
5. *W  X   →   B   X*
6. *B  X   →   B   c*

So *Aa → aA* is not a CSG rule in itself, but the langue it generates is. Perhaps whoever told you it is, was using it as a shorthand (you could expand the definition of CSG rules to include these types of things as "macros").